# Allowing port-forwarding on a Belkin wireless router

Tags: wireless-router, port-forwarding

Not sure on the exact model, but I have a Belkin wireless G router.

I would like to be able to ssh (amongst other activities) to my home machines from outside my home network.

I have DNS entries already setup for these purposes, so my only issue now is getting port-forwarding to work.

I'd like to run ssh on one external port (say, 106) to forward to one machine internally (on port 22), and open a different external port (maybe 3333) to forward to port 22 on a different machine on my network.

You can see from the this first screenshot the ports Skype has opened.

[image: skype ports work!]

And from the second one the port I'm trying to open.

[image: ssh doesn't :(]

However, the second opening is unsuccessful, while the first works like a champ.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What indication do you have it's not working?  Have you tried telnetting in on that port from the outside to see if you get through at all?

Comment: I can't telnet-through, nor ssh

Comment: You are positive it's not something silly like a software firewall on the target machine?

Comment: @JNK - not 100% positive, but I have sharing over ssh turned-on on the target Mac

Comment: @JNK - my timeout is happening on being unable to connect to the external port, not on authentication to the target device inside the network

Comment: OK let me research something.  The only thing I can think of is this router may have a problem mapping a diff internal vs external port (the ones that work all map to the same port).

Comment: @warren - OK, try (as an experiment) mapping external 22 to internal 22 on one machine.  If that works I think it may be an issue in the router firmware.

Comment: @JNK - found the option in the drop-down menu for the router configuration that lets you add 'secure shell' (on port 22) to the list: it's the same as what I had done, except with a range of 22-22 on both ends. Still no dice :( ..I'm attempting to avoid getting a new router, but know this is a cinch in the Linksys ones I've had in the past

Comment: I'll look through possible updates to the firmware

Comment: My guess is it's an issue with the firmware.  Belkins aren't the best for administration config like this.

Comment: @warren - happy to help, let me know if you get it figured out!

Comment: @JNK - Definitely will!